# Multiple file upload for one parameter inside model nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, file-upload, database-schema

I want to make a gallery to an artist. I got mostly everything done but I want to upload multiple imageFiles to one artist without making 1 model for 1 painting hand coded. Inside my Model i got `paintings: {type: String}` but i dont want paintings2, paintings3. Is there a way to count automatically and display any of them seperate to delete one. My file input is`<input type="file" class="filepond " name="paintings" value="<%= post.paintings %>" multiple>`
router
If you need more code I can send

Answer (score 0):

You can have the model schematype as `array`

change this

```
paintings: {type: String}
```

into

```
paintings:  [ { type: String} ]
```

reference : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays

please provide more detail / code if you are still having issue